# c++ loop getting slower on each iteration

Tags: c++, for-loop

In C++ I am using a nested for loop to match up pairs of objects that have the same names. I expected the program to take a long time to run (comparing thousands of strings) but as it progresses, the program runs slower and slower. It compares the first 20% of the strings within a few minutes, but once it reaches about 30% complete it is taking almost 60 seconds to check one string against the others.

I have my "new data" which contains proper values for the fields "feas", "eff" and "numIdeas", and my old data which shares the "data" field in common with its matching "new" partner. The new data and the old data are not in the same order and I can't sort them because the order that they are currently in is meaningful. I figured the best way would be to just "brute force" through it. Like I said, they are in no particular order so the extreme slowing down of the loop iterations was confusing to me. As far as I can tell the speed should stay constant.

```
for(int i=0; i< newDO.getNumItems(); i++)
{
    Item newItem = newDO.getItem(i);

    for(int k=0; k < oldDO.getNumItems(); k++)
    {
        Item oldItem = oldDO.getItem(k);
        if(oldItem.getType()==1)
        {
            bool same = testStrings(oldItem.getData(), newItem.getData());

            if(same)
            {
               oldItem.setFeas(newItem.getFeas());
               oldItem.setEff(newItem.getEff());
               oldItem.setNumIdeas(newItem.getNumIdeas());
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't write this `testStrings` function but I didn't see any real issue with it. This function takes the strings (which are about 5-20 chars) and takes out any spaces and '('.

(As I understand it the person before me had imported thousands of files before realizing that the function that was parsing them wasn't removing '(' properly from some of the data, so his fix for this was to just ignore them when checking if strings were equal).

```
bool testStrings(string s1, string s2)
{
    string s1def ="";
    for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s1[i]!=' ' || s1[i]!=')'){s1def+=s1[i];}
    }
    string s2def = "";
    for(int i=0; i<s2.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s2[i]!=' ' || s2[i]!=')'){s2def+=s2[i];}
    }
    if(s1def == s2def){return true;}
    else{return false;}
}
```

Any insight would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind providing real source code rather than pseudocode?

Comment: This is a *quadratic time algorithm* (assuming array1 and array2 are similar in size). It's almost certainly the wrong way to do it. However as others have said, cannot possibly suggest what the right way to do it is without proper code and better description of the problem.

Comment: i am a bit curious about getItem(), if you are comparing items it would seem that returning a reference to the item would be better than a copy .

Comment: I was just quickly trying to patch up some code that I "inherited." I am not the best with C++ in the first place (and this mostly un-commented code is fairly baffling at times).  Would passing a reference drastically speed up the process?

Comment: Not drastically, just marginally. I think you need to change the algorithm for a drastic speed up. Instead of having one loop inside the other, you need to sort the two lists. If they are sorted then you can loop though both lists in parallel, this will be drastically faster.

Answer (score 4):

This code could almost have been written as a demonstration of how to do everything wrong.

As @jahhaj already mentioned, you seem to be using a quadratic algorithm.

You're compounding that by stripping out the extra characters in the comparison function, because that means you're stripping out the extra characters every time you do a comparison, instead of just once up-front.

If I were doing it, I'd start by creating a struct like:

```
struct index { 
   std::string key;
   size_t subscript;
}
```

You'll initialize this by copying the string you're comparing into `key`, and the subscript of that item into `subscript`.

Then walk through and strip out the extra characters (' ' and ')') from those strings. Then sort these arrays, comparing only the `key` field. Then use `std::set_intersection` to find the common items.

By copying and sorting the keys, you'll be able to take advantage of sorting without affecting the (significant) existing order of the data. By stripping out the extra characters up-front, you'll do the stripping on each key only once. By using `set::intersection`, you get the common items with linear complexity instead of quadratic.

The obvious shortcoming is that copying the strings obviously increases the amount of data you have to store. If, however, the number of items is large enough for that to make much difference, then you also have enough that going from quadratic to linear complexity will represent a *huge* time savings. Copying the data will be justified, even if it means you have to write other data out to disk temporarily to do it.

Answer (score 3):

1) We can't really say anything for sure without a) seeing more of your actual code, and b) understanding your data set.

2) It doesn't look like you're "adding" anything, or "growing" any structures.

... but (and this is just a guess) ....

3) Let's say both arrays are sorted: array1 = {1, 2, 3, ... 999}; array2 = {1, 3, 4, ... 1001}.

In your early iterations, you'll quickly hit the "break".  For example, array1[0] will match array2[0] before you even loop once.

In your later iterations, however, you'll have to execute the inner loop 100's or more times to find the item you're looking for.

Perhaps the whole problem is a) iteratively performing b) a linear search c) of an ordered data set.

Again - just a guess.

IMHO...

Comment: "to find the item you're looking for ..." or ***not find it at all***, having looped through the whole array2. Which might just be the real culprit.

Comment: @user1551885 - thank you for editing your post and showing us the actual code - it helps *enormously*.  It sounds like Jerry Coffin has the solution - throw away your current algorithm, and use the standard library (string::compare, set::intersection, etc) to do the "heavy lifting" for you.  This is a good overview if you need help: http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/HOWTO/C++Programming-HOWTO-17.html

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for the slowdown here can be data-centric, if your new collection is huge, and contains lots of new items not present in the old collection, in which case the whole new collection will get searched for each one string from the old.

Do follow the advice by Jerry Coffin, copy your collections with the cleaned up strings, sort them according to `string::compare`, and then iterate over the two of them in a linear fashion like `std::merge` is doing:

```
1  2  4 5   8  10 11 12 14 17 20 24  ...
1  2  4  6  8  10             20       50 ...
```

Since you need to update your original items in the old collection, add another field to each of its items' copies, carrying a *pointer to the original item* being copied, and update *that* when the duplicate is found. Then discard both copies.

What are the sizes of your two collections?

Answer (score -1):

How did you measure the performance? Actually, there can be many reasons of such behavior (algorithm issues, cpu cache, compiler settings), but it's very difficult to answer your question without seeing the source code and actual string data which your code working with...  And can you show your implementation of string comparison algorithm?